# How to prevent closing of a ViewModel (and the canceling of the Model) in Catel

Tags: catel

I need to prevent a ViewModel from closing and also prevent the Model editing from being canceled.  I tried overriding OnClosing in the ViewModel, but that event came too late.  It came after the Model editing was canceled.  (Seems like strange order of event to me.)

I found an old question and answer that said to use OnViewModelCanceling, however that method does not exist as an overrideable in the current version.

I found the OnViewModelEvent, but alias, it does not get called for any event on my ViewModel.

So, is the correct solution to override Cancel on the ViewModel and return false, or must one register for the Canceling event on the ViewModel?

I have tried using the override of Cancel and doing so works for a simple ViewModel.  However, if the current ViewModel has nested controls with ViewModels and they too return false from Cancel, the outer ViewModel never even gets a crack at Cancel.  (Which makes sense.)  My issue here is that sometimes I DO want to honor the Cancel and the outer ViewModel knows that, but the nested ViewModels do not.  I know that I can solve this in many ways, but I would like to know if there is a better way to prevent the canceling of the edit of the Model before I solve this new issue.

This may violate the one question per question rule, but it is extremely closely related.  I also need to know how to allow a ViewModel to close, but NOT do an EndEdit (or CancelEdit) on its Models.

WPF application using Catel 3.9

Answer (score 0):

You can override Save() and return false. Preventing a user control not to close will be hard to achieve because that will be very hard to understand for the end user.

Make sure *not* to call the base before returning false, because the base.Save() and base.Cancel() will kick in the model editing.

Comment: I am confused by your statement that calling base.Save() and base.Cancel will kick in the model editing.  The code in 3.9 lines 1520 1nd 1528 of ViewModelBase simply return True.  I agree that returning false does stop the edit, but it also (at least the way I have things coded) prevent the close of the View and the window continues to display.

Comment: I am sorry, you don't have to do anything with the base. That was a long time ago, didn't remember that I already changed that :-). As you can see in the source, returning false for both cancel and save should prevent models being handled. See https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/develop/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.NET40/MVVM/ViewModels/ViewModelBase.cs#L1380

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the way I have things coded, return false from either Save or Cancel, prevents the View from closing.  Is that expected behavior or do I have something miswired?

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior. If you don't want Catel to manage the models, then you can do it yourself in 2 ways:

1) Remove the Model attribute
2) Use the Model attribute with SupportIEditableObject = false